# Discord.py - bot responding if message only contains a certain word

Tags: discord.py

instead of the user message starting with '!quit', is there a way that the message can only be '!quit' as opposed to only needing to start with it?

```
    if message.content.startswith('!quit'):
        await message.channel.send("Goodbye!")
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly the question, you can check if the message is strictly equal to `!quit` using a **double equal** symbol (opposed to the single equal symbol which is used to set the value a variable)

```py
    if message.content == '!quit':
        await message.channel.send("Goodbye!")
        sys.exit()
```

If you also want to accept commands like `!Quit` or `!QUIT`, you could first transform the incomming messages using `message.content.lower()` which would give :

```py
    if message.content.lower() == '!quit':
        await message.channel.send("Goodbye!")
        sys.exit()
```

**As a bonus**, you can also check if a string is somewhere in the message using

```py
    if '!quit' in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("Goodbye!")
        sys.exit()
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Tried this before and i got an error but it started working now that I put it again, thanks